# Proving inequalities with analysis

Tags: analysis, inequality, proof-writing

Suppose that for all $0<c \in \mathbb{R}$ that $a < bc + b$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $b \geq a$ and $b \geq 0$.

My attempt:

We start by considering $a < bc + b$. We have that

$$a < bc + b \implies bc + b  - a > 0$$

Using the archimedian property of real numbers, it follows

$$bc + b - a > \frac{1}{n}$$

$$nbc + nb  - na > 1$$

Now, by the archimedian property involving integers, there is an $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that we have

$$m \leq nbc + nb < m + 1$$

This is as far as I have gotten with this proof, and I'm not sure if I'm even right thus far. I am new to this topic and I am not sure how to manipulate the archimedian property/ies to complete the proof. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$a<bc+b$

We know that this must be true for any real number $c$ greater than, but not equal, to 0. Let's first assume $b>0$, then we can establish an upper bound for $a$ by letting $c$ approach zero.

$a<\lim_{c\to 0}(bc+b)\  \to \ (a<b)$

Since $c$ cannot equal zero, than $a=b$ also satisfies $a<bc+b$.
Therefore:

$b>0\Rightarrow a\leq b$

Let's consider when $b<0$.

$a<\lim_{c\to\infty}(bc+b)\ \to \ (a<-\infty)$

This is impossible.

$b\nless 0$

Lets consider when $b=0$

$a<bc+b$
$a<0c+0$
$a<0$

This is a perfectly valid possibility.

Therefore:

$b\geq 0$

$b \geq a$